# monitoring SMS messages' text contents, time information, and location information

Tags: android, geolocation, sms, monitoring

I'd appreciate some directions or suggestions. Where must I begin in order to develop an app with the following capabilities:

1. Whenever a user sends/receives a SMS message via any SMS messaging-capable app, my app records (in any file format):

   - the text content of the SMS message, and
   - the time at which the SMS message was sent/received
2. Record, in any file format, the geolocation information of the user's phone at regular time intervals (ex: every 30 minutes).

I have an introductory knowledge of Java; currently, I'm learning tutorial 26 (of 200) on The New Boston. Is my goal beyond what I am currently capable of? Thank you in advance for your help!

Note: For those curious, such an app would be used for a study that monitors patients suffering from emotion dysregulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your environment has already been setup.

1. Had you been interested only in received SMS', a broadcast receiver for SMS received would have worked for you (http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.sg/2010/10/receiving-sms-using-broadcastreceiver.html). For sent and received, you can try setting up a ContentObserver on the SMS Content Provider. Here's a starting point: http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/sms-mms-contentobserver-and-service-t12938.html. Dump this data into your data store.
2. Use this tutorial to record locations: http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html. Specifically, http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html will tell you how to get periodic updates. Dump this into your data store.

As for your data storage system, you have a bunch of options including the cloud, a local SQLite DB and Shared Preferences. On the outset, it looks like the cloud is a good option. Here's a training for cloud sync: http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html

This will get you going.

Comment: Thank you kindly for answering my question! I will definitely head in that direction. I'll have to obtain familiarity with SQLite using The New Boston tutorials. I will let you know how it all goes.